# How to determine the proper HTML5 video codec attribute for an AV1 file based on the FFMpeg encoding command or output?

Tags: video, encoding, ffmpeg, html5-video, codec

We have some files encoded in AV1, but we recently noticed that Chrome mobile fails to play the files - but it doesn't fall back to an encoding it can use - it just puts the unplayable AV1 file in there. I'm hoping that if we add a codec attribute we can remedy this - but I'm not sure how to determine the codec for these AV1 files.

I've come across [this documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Formats/codecs_parameter#AV1), but I'm not sure how I would determine the proper codec from that. It starts off simple enough, but some of the values further down, I have no idea what the right value would be.

Opening the file in VLC player only shows this very limited information about the codec:

[image]

### The output of [MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/MediaInfoOnline) is:

```
General
Complete name                            : demo-av1.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom (isom/iso2/mp41)
File size                                : 291 KiB
Duration                                 : 1 min 40 s
Overall bit rate                         : 23.7 kb/s
Writing application                      : Lavf58.43.100

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AV1
Format/Info                              : AOMedia Video 1
Format profile                           : High@L3.0
Codec ID                                 : av01
Duration                                 : 1 min 40 s
Bit rate                                 : 22.9 kb/s
Width                                    : 984 pixels
Height                                   : 670 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 3:2
Frame rate mode                          : Constant / Constant
Frame rate                               : 24.000 FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:4:4
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive / Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.001
Stream size                              : 281 KiB (96%)
Color range                              : Limited
Codec configuration box                  : av1C / av1C
```

### The command to create the files and the output of FFMpeg is like so:

```sh
ffmpeg -y -i "D:\RAW VIDEO\Demos\demo.avi" -ss 00:00:00  -c:v libaom-av1 -pix_fmt yuv444p -minrate 500 -b:v 48k -maxrate 1000k -strict experimental -movflags +faststart -f mp4 NUL && ffmpeg -y -i "D:\RAW VIDEO\Demos\demo.avi" -ss 00:00:00  -c:v libaom-av1 -pix_fmt yuv444p -minrate 500 -b:v 48k -maxrate 1000k -strict experimental -movflags +faststart -pass 2 "D:\RAW VIDEO\Demos\converted\demo-av1.mp4"
ffmpeg version git-2020-05-22-38490cb Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.3.1 (GCC) 20200513

  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --disable-w32threads --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 46.100 / 56. 46.100
  libavcodec     58. 86.101 / 58. 86.101
  libavformat    58. 43.100 / 58. 43.100
  libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
  libavfilter     7. 82.100 /  7. 82.100
  libswscale      5.  6.101 /  5.  6.101
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100

Input #0, avi, from 'D:\RAW VIDEO\Demos\demo.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration:
00:00:23.43, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 19719 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: huffyuv (HFYU / 0x55594648), bgr0, 420x240, 19739 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc

Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (huffyuv (native) -> av1 (libaom-av1))

Press [q] to stop, [?] for help

[libaom-av1 @ 00000000003fb3c0] v1.0.0

Output #0, mp4, to 'NUL':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.43.100

    Stream #0:0: Video: av1 (libaom-av1) (av01 / 0x31307661), yuv444p, 420x240, q=-1--1, 48 kb/s, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.86.101 libaom-av1
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
```

Comment: Fwiw, I wrote an article on this process https://jakearchibald.com/2022/html-codecs-parameter-for-av1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## av01.1.04M.08.0.000.02.02.02.02.0

Represents the following components: `av01.P.LLT.DD.M.CCC.cp.tc.mc.F`.

| Component | Your video | Resulting Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P | Format profile: **High**@L3.0 | 1 |
| LLT | Format profile: High@**L3.0**, Main tier | 04M |
| DD | Bit depth: 8 bits | 08 |
| M | Not monochrome (its not black & white) | 0 |
| CCC | Chroma subsampling: YUV 4:4:4 | 000 |
| cp | unknown | 02 |
| tc | unknown | 02 |
| mc | unknown | 02 |
| F | Color range: Limited | 0 |

- [The "codecs" parameter in common media types: AV1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Formats/codecs_parameter#AV1) will link to the appropriate sections of the AV1 specification which provides helpful tables of values.
- `mediainfo` and `ffprobe` will tell you if `cp` (color primaries), `tc` (transfer characteristics), and `mc` (matrix coefficients) are not unknown. Since these are not listed in your `mediainfo` output, and you did not use the associated encoding options (`-colorspace`, `-color_trc`, `-color_primaries`), the value is therefore unknown.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to explain! I very much doubted I would ever receive a response for this one, let alone an answer.