# Chrome won't play AV1 encoded files if we define the codec in the type attribute - but browsers that can't play AV1 fail if we leave it out

Tags: google-chrome, video, html5-video, playback, codec

I'm sort of at a loss for how to zero in on a fix for this.

We have a file that is an AV1 encoded MP4, and we have some fallback files for older browsers. Only we hit this issue:

**If we DO define the codec:** Chrome for desktop won't play the AV1 file - it uses the fallbacks

**If we DO NOT define the codec:** Chrome for desktop will play the AV1 file, but mobile browsers that don't support AV1 will try and fail to play the file, rather than using a fallback.

We've tried:

- `type="video/mp4"` (Mobile playback fails)
- `type="video/mp4; codecs=av01"` (All browsers use fallback, ignoring AV1 file)
- `type="video/mp4; codecs=av01.1.04M.08.0.000.02.02.02.02.0"` (All browsers use fallback, ignoring AV1 file) ([Source for that string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65384551/6025788))

---

The actual HTML source we're using is like this:

```html
<video muted="" loop="" preload="metadata">
    <source src="./demo-av1.mp4#t=0" type="video/mp4; codecs=av1">
    <source src="./demo.webm#t=0" type="video/webm">
    <source src="./demo-x264.mp4#t=0" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with just `av01.1.04M.08` (the other stuff seems to be optional from what I see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Formats/codecs_parameter#av1))?

I just tried a video of mine like this:

```html
<video muted="" loop="" preload="metadata">
    <source src="./demo-av1.mp4#t=0" type="video/mp4; codecs=av01.0.05M.08,opus">
    <source src="./demo.webm#t=0" type="video/webm">
    <source src="./demo-x264.mp4#t=0" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

... and tested it on:

- Chrome - loads the AV1
- Safari - loads the fallback videos without loading any AV1 resources (if you skip the codecs string at all, Safari still uses the fallback but in the network tab you can see it loads part of the AV1 file).

[Source for that codecs string](https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/better-web-video-with-av1-codec)

Comment: I'll have to give that a try. It'll be some time before I can loop back. Thanks for sharing!